# How to check 'NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M' is installed, lspci not showing the model?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hardware

How can i confirm whether NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M 2GB is installed on my ubuntu laptop?

lspci is showing '08:00.0 3D controller : NVIDIA Corporation Device 1140 (rev ff)'

does this mean 'NVIDIA GeForce GT 820M' is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Check the nvidia's propietary driver from Start menu-> Preferences->Software & Updates. Cheers